# How to run any (Chrome, Firefox, PhantomJS) browser in selenium server standalone?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-server

***My Question or Problem = I cannot run any browser with selenium remote server, how do I fix this?***

My environment:

- Operating System Windows 10
- I'm using eclipse(Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)) with java 1.8
- selenium Web driver 3.0.0
- selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

I start selenium-server-standalone in cmd.
("selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" the file is stored in the utilities folder on my c drive )

```
C:\Windows\system32> cd\
C:\> cd utilities
C:\Utilities> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

[image]

Then selenium-server-standalone starts and everything looks fine

[image]

**When I run my tests**

Eclipse provides this error:

```
Feb 09, 2017 10:36:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Feb 09, 2017 10:36:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Feb 09, 2017 10:36:36 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{marionette=true, browserName=firefox, version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'
System info: host: 'MWLTSHAUNCR', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

In cmd I received this error:
[image]

My code looks something like this for the remoteDriver part that I have added. I have included the class and constructor

```
public class browser {
    private  browser (WebDriver driver){ 
        browser.driver = driver;
    }

    public static void runRemoteDriver(){
        try {
            WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
            new browser (webDriver);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I copied all the driver to folder where I store the "selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar" file. Then it worked!!!

[image]

I started server with cmd command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar
```

then in you code you must specify which browser you want to run for example:

```
    WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
    WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.chrome());
    WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the path for your driver.exe file. You have two options:

1.you can either use *System.setProperty()*,  in the way you do generally.

2.you can start the RemoteDriver using the path as shown below.

```
java -Dphantomjs.binary.path=phantomjs.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

and this line of code is responsible for establishing the connection.

```
WebDriver webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```