# Running Selenium Tests through Linux Server

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, putty, selenium-grid

This is a general question, but I want to run my Selenium tests on a cloud Linux Server. I am accessing this server using PuTTY, which is just a terminal.

I was wondering how I could get my Selenium scripts to run on this VM.

Currently I have a Selenium Grid set up with physical machines, I just do not know how to set one up through a server where the only communication I have with it is through PuTTY and a terminal.

Comment: The same way. Launch hub and nodes, then your Tests. Copy all dependencies using scp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run Selenium from a Linux server that is "terminal only", as you put it, is to install a GUI inside of the server.

The most common GUI to use, is Xvfb.  There are plenty of tutorials out there on how to run GUI programs like Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox through Xvfb.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PhantomJS to do a headless Automation, that doesn't need any GUI installation on Server.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. That is true, but I would still need to install the driver and the selenium standalone on my server right

Comment: In our case the execution was on a windows server. We don't have to do an installation. All we needed was to refer to phantomJS.exe location while setting up driver Capabilities.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: you can refer to the following post. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132165/how-to-run-any-chrome-firefox-phantomjs-browser-in-selenium-server-standalon/45110315#45110315)

Comment: sometimes headless can't be the solution!